# Why are Solace messages hanging on the server on restart after Camel 3 upgrade?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, solace, solace-mq, camel-jms

On upgrading to Camel 3.3 we came accorss an issue while testing. So, if we restart our camel application while there are multiple messages in the queue for some reason a few messages are getting stuck in an "unacknowledged" state on the solace queue and after the appliation comes back up it doesn't consume those messages. We need to resart the application once more before they get consumed.

1. This issues only seems to occur only when there are a large number of messages in the queue at the time of restart.
2. We have not been able to recreate the issue on Camel 2.x versions.
3. The application is correctly setup to AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE and it works normally in all other circumstances.
4. "acceptMessagesWhileStopping" is set to false.
5. We haven't seen any message loss or duplication.

We went through all the setup and configuration that happens at startup and we haven't found any issues with either the setup or configuration. I am not sure how to go about with debugging this as this is a shutdown related issue that too while messages are in the process of consumption. Any advice on how to go forward would be helpful. Regards.

P.S. I have gone through the Camel 3 migration guides. I didn't find anything pertinent to the issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of camel 3 doesn't seem to have this issue.